# Handle json response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want create a query to a api url and  save the params that a URL give me back as a JSON.
Let me put it this way, i have a url like this:

http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instance_Create?username=userXXX&password=secret&languageCode=en&generatorID=45&imageID=20&text0=push a hipster down the stairs&text1=now look who's tumbling

And I want send the parameters so the api gives me back my data as json....

I am trying to create a form like this...

```
<%= form_for(@meme,  :url => "memeapi", :remote => true)  do |f| %>  
    <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :memeid %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :memeid %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :imgid %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :imgid %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text0 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text0 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :text1 %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :text1 %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

I am pretty sure the answer is to send this params to the controller and then handle the request something like this

```
def memeapi
      @meme = Meme.new(params[:meme])
      @apiurl = "version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instance_Create?username=apigen&password=koalass&languageCode=en&generatorID=#{@meme.memeid}&imageID=#{@meme.imgid}&text0=#{@meme.text0}&text1=#{@meme.text1}"
      redirect_to @apiurl 
      @meme.url = "#{@meme.name}-#{@meme.id}" 

  end
```

I cant figure out how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> require 'net/http'
>
> ```
> url = "http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instance_Create?username=apigen&password=koalass&languageCode=en&generatorID=#{@meme.memeid}&imageID=#{@meme.imgid}&text0=#{@meme.text0}&text1=#{@meme.text1}"
> resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
> data = resp.body
> # we convert the returned JSON data to native Ruby
> # data structure - a hash
> result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)
> ```

Comment: Ok, but how can I see the get_repsonse is working? I canteven format the result variable, how can I see what gives me back?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html that is response object , you can also handle status and message